# Using Union with Insert to add one row

Tags: sql, union, teradata

I have a query which is made up of two select statements with a union in the middle.
This works for what I need it for.
However, there is one value missing which I want to manually enter.
What I'm looking to is:

```
select * from tab1
union
select * from tab2
union
insert values('John',cast('2013-01-01' as date), 'Jim', 130)
```

Unfortunately this is not working. Can someone suggest how I do this please?
I'm using Teradata.

Comment: This question demonstrated the helpfulness of indicating which database/version you are using, as the answer is product specific.

Comment: Very true, I'm starting to appreciate database nuances

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to keep selecting:

```
select * from tab1
union
select * from tab2
union
select 'John', cast('2013-01-01' as date), 'Jim', 130 from dual
```

The name `dual` is used in Oracle for a table with one row (and one column).  Depending on the DBMS you use, you may be able to omit that final FROM altogether (and you may be able to do this in Oracle too):

```
select * from tab1
union
select * from tab2
union
select 'John', cast('2013-01-01' as date), 'Jim', 130
```

or you may have to choose from a system catalog table and ensure you get one row returned (`FROM systables WHERE tabid = 1` was the classic mechanism in Informix, though you could also use `'sysmaster':sysdual` instead of `dual`, etc, too), or you can select from any other table with a query that is guaranteed one row.  There are probably ways to do it using a VALUES clause too.

Note the change from double quotes to single quotes.  In strict standard SQL, double quotes enclose a delimited identifier, but single quotes surround strings.

Comment: What does `SELECT "hello world"` give in Oracle, an empty set?

Comment: @AndreKR: Dunno; I've not used Oracle enough.  Once upon a standard version of SQL from a long time ago, a FROM clause was mandatory.  As I noted, you may well be able to without the final FROM clause, but I don't know which DBMS support that notation (and which version they support it since — where that isn't lost in the mists of antiquity).  I've been doing SQL for 25 years; I haven't completely lost all the constraints that were necessary 25 years ago but aren't any more.  And, judging from the new comments, you still need to SELECT from `dual` in Oracle in a UNION query.

Comment: thanks for this suggestion. I'm using Teradata. When I tried this it returned 'Syntax error, expected something like a name or a unicode delimited identifier or '(' between the 'from' keyword and the 'dual' @JonathanLeffler

Comment: Since there's mention of 'delimited identifier', the double-quoted strings are presumably being interpreted as 'delimited identifiers'.  Replace the double quotes by single quotes; maybe that will work correctly.  On the other hand, it also mentions that it does not understand `FROM dual`, so you may have to resort to one of the other subterfuges.  I don't know the Teradata system catalog, but the Informix query selects the entry for 'systables' from 'systables'.

Comment: I noticed that, I changed that to single quote, that's when I received the above mentioned message @JonathanLeffler

Comment: I see from [Teradata SQL Quick Reference](http://tunweb.teradata.ws/tunstudent/TeradataUserManuals/Teradata_SQL_Quick_Reference.pdf) that DUAL is a keyword in Teradata SQL (used in an ALTER TABLE statement).  Thus, it seems you'll have to play the '`SELECT ...literals... FROM ...table expression that generates one row...`' trick.

Comment: I think you can use: `... union select * from
(select 'John', cast('2013-01-01' as date), 'Jim', 130) x`

Comment: Apparently teradata does not use dual, however, by putting from sys_calendar.calendar instead of dual it gave me the results I was looking for. For some people they will also have to add WHERE Calendar_Date = Current_Date. Thank you for your help Jonathan, it led me down the correct path

Comment: OTOH, reading the quick reference, it looks as though the FROM clause is optional and it should have worked, but then you got the error with 'select for union, intersect or minus must reference a table', so there's a gotcha that a syntax diagram doesn't reveal.  So, you'll need to find the system catalog information — maybe from [Teradata](http://www.info.teradata.com/templates/eSrchResults.cfm?prodline=&txtpid=&txtrelno=&txtttlkywrd=SQLREF,TNTSEQ&rdsort=Title&srtord=Asc&nm=SQL+Reference).

Comment: @ypercube: I think you'd need to name the columns in the inner SELECT using that notation — though as I don't have Teradata to play with, that is not a foregone conclusion.  But the general scheme you outline might well work as an alternative to the restriction-on-catalog option.

Comment: I can't test either. This may not need any naming: `... union
select 'John', cast('2013-01-01' as date), 'Jim', 130 from (select 1 x) y` and looks closer to a "dual" table.

Comment: It's a bit strange in Teradata: You don't need a FROM unless the select is part of a UNION/INTERSECT/EXCEPT. Teradata is almost as old as Oracle (they started 1979) and at that point in time there was no SQL, yet. The language was based on QUEL and called TeQuel, apparently you didn't need a FROM in that language. When they switched to Standard SQL they kept most of the old syntax rules but the new syntax was added according to SQL. SELECT ... FROM sys_calendar.calendar WHERE calendar_date = DATE; is typically used because there's PUBLIC access right and it's a fast primary index acces.

Answer (score 1):

You just want to `SELECT` the data, not `INSERT` it.

Not very familiar with TeraData, perhaps you need a `FROM` in which case limiting to 1 record would also make sense:

```
select * from tab1
union
select * from tab2
union
SELECT 'John',cast('2013-01-01' as date), 'Jim', '130' FROM dbc.columns 1
```

Comment: @Goat_CO when I try this I get an error message stating, 'A select for  a union, intersect or minus must reference a table'

Comment: Teradata, sorry, should have mentioned that in the post @GoatCO

Comment: Perhaps you can limit to one record and not reference fields from a system table.  Also not sure about single vs double quotes, so might need to make those double again.

Answer (score 1):

From your question I' guessing you just want to *SELECT* that row, not *INSERT* it (into the database):

```
select * from tab1
union
select * from tab2
union
select "John", cast('2013-01-01' as date), "Jim", 130
```

Comment: when I try this I get an error message stating, 'A select for  a union, intersect or minus must reference a table'

Answer (score 0):

I am affraid the union must reference a table and if you need to add the data that does not exist in your database, try this:

```
select * from tab1
union
select * from tab2
union
select * from (SELECT 'John' as col1 ,cast('2013-01-01' as date) as col2, 'Jim' as col3, '130' as col4) dummy
```

You will, of course, have to change the name of the columns to fit those from your db (i.e. dont use col1, col2 etc.).

Good luck!